# Python: list index out of range?

Tags: list, indexing, range, out

I can't figure this out... Why does this not work?

line 20, in placeBoat
    boatCoordinates = [xBoat][yBoat]
IndexError: list index out of range

```
def placeBoat():
    xBoat = randint(1,9)
    yBoat = randint(1,9)
    boatCoordinates = [xBoat][yBoat]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def placeBoat():
    return ( randint(1,9) , randint(1,9) ,)
```